# How to add keys to hashtable from a List in the same order in C#

Tags: c#, list, hashtable

I have a integer List `List<int> iFaciltyReqId = new List<int>();` and its elements are
[image]

I need to order the hashtable below like the above List(need to exclude if the element not exist)

My hashtable is 
[image]

Result should be hastable keys in the order 
1153
1168
1155
1152
1176
676

I tried as below, but the result is not meeting my expectation

```
foreach (var c in iFaciltyReqId)
            {

                foreach (var d in ohmItemSeqs.Keys)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(c) == Convert.ToInt32(d))
                    {
                        sortedohmItemSeqs.Add(c, ohmItemSeqs.Values);
                    }
                }
            }
```

and result was [image]
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you'd provide a [mcve] as *text*, all in one piece, rather than several screenshots and just snippets of code.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you simply take your list and return everything that's also in the hash table like so:

```
var result = yourList.Where(i => yourHashTable.Contains(i)); // works for both HashSet<int> and Hashtable
```

Comment: Similarly, `yourList.Intersect(yourHashTable)` also works, and I find it _slightly_ more readable because of not needing `Contains`.

Comment: @Flater: It works. But it is slower (it creates a new `Set` internally) and you need to understand what `Intersect` means which I personally find harder than a "where...contains". ;)

Comment: @dnickless... It gives an error message when tried,

Comment: @Sarat: I see... You are using a "real" Hashtable and not a HashSet<int>. I have update the syntax above to work for both.

Comment: @dnickless... Thank you... It really works... How can I convert this to a hash table of same order, can you please help

Comment: As @sbsd and others pointed out in their answer and comments this is technically impossible. A hashtable does not guarantee any order due to the way it works. Can you not simply proceed with the list? You could e.g. change some of your called methods to accept an IEnumerable instead of a Hashtable.

Answer (score 1):

A `Hashtable` is fundamentally an unordered data structure, so you'll want to look at alternatives if maintaining order is important.

If you want the order to be determined by insertion, `OrderedDictionary` may be a suitable option, although that depends on what your other needs for the object are.

Comment: I need to use hashtable since it has some more overloaded methods using the same hashtable as parameter...Is there any way to use order should be based on insertion

Comment: @Sarat: No, the order in hashtable is fundamentally not guaranteed. It's not clear to me what you mean by "since it has some more overloaded methods using the same hashtable as parameter". Note that Hashtable should almost always be avoided now, along with the other non-generic collections.

Comment: @DaisyShipton...you are right. Now I am trying to use dictionary instead of hashtable. But when I read dictionary using for each it breaks after first iteration. Could you please suggest. I am shring a sample code here  int z = 0;
                foreach (int iSeq in dictionary.Keys)
                {
                    dictionary[iSeq] = z++;
                }